# I know my passphrase. I don't remember specifically how I entered it

Tags: decryption

First if this is the wrong place to post this please forgive me.

I know my passphrase. I don't remember specifically how I entered it. ex. If the phrase is "The house at the end is blue and white. I like it." I would have used the first letters of each word... "thateibawili" My problem is I can't remember if I, in this example, remember If the first "t" and the second "I" is capitalized and if I used the punctuation.

I am not a programmer. Since I know the passphrase is there a program that can run through the variations of it with the possible cap letters and punctuation?

Thanks

Comment: It depends a lot on what this is a passphrase for, and what interface(s) you have available to test guesses on. Also, whether you can create a computer-readable pattern of possible passphrases.

Comment: This is probably not the place, presumably you need more than a few guesses you try by hand. You will probably need custom code to enumerate the custom passphrase space which letters may be capitalized where might there be punctuation etc. You will also need a way to test many guesses, if it's for something offline like a crypto wallet, or an encrypted document no problem, for a well designed website probably impractical.

Comment: Indeed, tools like hashcat should be able to accept existing knowledge about a passphrase like you have and will be able to systematically try all possible variants if this passphrase is used to encrypt some offline document.